# URL System Links not working

Tags: menu, menu-item, url, weblinks

I don't know if this is a bug or if this is something new with Joomla 4, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

In Joomla 2 and 3, I would create menu items of the URL System Links type that sent users to external sites. However, now on Joomla 4 when I create the same type of menu item and try to visit the alias, I get a 404 error and it says 'Component Not Found'. It only happens on this type of menu item, any other type works fine.

Am I missing something? Is there a new setting in Joomla 4, or is this the expected behavior now?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Checked with a complete url like `https://www.marca.com` (with https://), and works as expected. Links without http... are internal links.

Comment: The link in a menu, yes it works. But I'm talking about the alias that gets generated. For instance my site domain is 'mysite.org' and I create a menu item with an alias of 'mylink' inside of the main menu.  if I got to 'mysite.org/mylink' I get that 404 'Component Not Found' error message. If I click on the 'mylin' menu item in the main menu, then yes it does work. Are you saying you don't have this issue?

Comment: I get same behavior as you describe, sorry.